# Get values in 2nd combobox from text according to the key in the first combobox using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, database, winforms, combobox

I create two combobox in my code. The first one I use to show the city name of Germany Like Flensburg,Kiel,Lübeck. It is shown in the combobox following way

```
   Flensburg
   Kiel
   Lübeck
```

I got this list from .xls file.I a separate class to get this value. the code I use to get this value is as follows

```
            class PlaceList
                {

                    public static ComboBox Combo_list = new ComboBox();
                    public static DataGridView dataTable = new DataGridView();

                    public static void List()
                    {

                        var startPath = Application.StartupPath;
                        string folderName = Path.Combine(startPath, "POI_List");
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
                        string SavedfileName = "POI_list.json";
                        var Saving_path = Path.Combine(folderName, SavedfileName);

                        string fileName = "Zensus_Gemeinden_org.xlsx";
                        var path = Path.Combine(startPath, fileName);

                        String name = "Gemeinden_31.12.2011_Vergleich";
                        String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                                       path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";

                        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
                        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select [3] as City,[4] as Population, * From [" + name + "$D7:E11300] Where [4] > 10000", con);
                        con.Open();

                        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
                        DataTable data = new DataTable();

                        sda.Fill(data);
                        dataTable.DataSource = data;



                        for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            Combo_list.Items.Add(data.Rows[i]["City"]);
                        }


                        string Place_Json = "Place_List:" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
                        File.WriteAllText(Saving_path, Place_Json);

                    }
                }
```

Then in the form1.cs I call this city names is as following way

```
 public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();


        PlaceList.Combo_list = comboBox1;
    }
```

This part is working perfectly for me.Now the next step is to read a text file where I write several Point of interest for each places list like this

```
   Flensburg,Berlin Wall,Brandenburg Gate,Reichstag Building
   Kiel,Nymphenburg palace,Museum Island,Marienplatz
   Lübeck,Old Castle,Staatsgalerie Stuttgart,schlossplatz stuttgart
```

I want to get this value according to the click of the first combobox1. suppose If someone click at Flensburg, he can see every value in the second combobox.To get this I use following code in Form1.cs

```
  Dictionary<string, List<string>> poi = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
      private void LoadKeys()
    {

       foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("TextFile1.txt"))
                {
                    string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    poi.Add(parts[0], new List<string>(parts.Skip(1)));
                }

    }

    void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            string txt = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            if (poi.ContainsKey(txt))
            {
                List<string> points = poi[txt];
                comboBox2.Items.Clear();
                comboBox2.Items.AddRange(points.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
```

But it is not working at all.It does not show any value to combobox 2. Can I do it in different way. Sorry for long description.

Comment: try to put break-point into comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged and see what actually happen

Comment: string txt = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); got Flensburg, then  if (poi.ContainsKey(txt)) also got Flensburg.   List<string> points = poi[txt]; also got Flensburg. But I do not get why it is not showing any value in combobox 2

Comment: check what is inside poi

Comment: inside poi I saw poi, count =0 @volody

Comment: add LoadKeys to the Form Load or after PlaceList.Combo_list = comboBox1 in Form1 constructor

Comment: Thank you very much it is working now. @volody.

Comment: @volody: A new exception is curring in my code on line poi.Add(parts[0], new List<string>());